# How would mining pools prevent fake hash rates from quantum computers?

Tags: attack, quantum-computing

This question is related to other two:

quora - [How do mining pools prevent fake hash rates?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-mining-pools-prevent-fake-hash-rates#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20fake%20your,ve%20submitted%20enough%20work%20recently)

reddit - [How do mining pools prevent fake hashrates?](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/6ieb4q/how_do_mining_pools_prevent_fake_hashrates/?rdt=53150)

The answers are far from being useful. For example,

One answer is:

> They count the **shares** you found, **not your hashrate**.

It is well know [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) can be used to attack SHA256
(read [Applying Grover's Algorithm to Hash Functions A Software Perspective](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=10014648)).

In practice, quantum computer hardwares are still slow and we expect they will beat classical ones in bitcoin mining in the not-too-distant future.

So why there is no way yet to prevent a **quantum** **HONEST*** attack to SHA256?

*by honest I mean just a method to find nonces by applying Grover to SHA256 and not a 51% attack.

Answer (score -2):

Introduction of Quantum Resistant Hash Functions: Mining pools have the option of using specific hash functions, such as the Quantum Resistant Hash function, which is designed to be resistant to attacks by quantum computers, thus increasing the security of the hash.

Comment: This doesn't seem very helpful as an answer and looks a lot like a ChatGPT or other LLM generated answer. Which QRH do you refer to? How can it be applied by mining pools specifically? Wouldn't that affect other non-mining nodes and non-pool mining farms?